# Seeding 0.0 to 1.0 uniform pseudorandom generator with value outside of range

Tags: python, random

Edit:

random.random() returns values from 0.0 to 1.0

How does seeding with numbers outside of these bounds (0.0-1.0) work? The wiki page says seeds are used to "initialize" the generator. What does the generator do with the seed to keep it within these bounds?

It isn't clear to me how you could use a large # such as 10000 to initialize a function that will return values from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.random()` returns values from `0.0` to `1.0`, but it's based on the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) algorithm, a pseudorandom number generator that works entirely with integers. When `random.random()` is called, a float value in that range is generated from the integer data.

According to the docs for [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed), when the seed is an `int`, it's used directly as the seed for the Mersenne Twister. Integers work as seeds because the underlying algorithm works with integers.

You may have been confused by the statement that

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function `random()`, …

This seems to be referring to two things:

1. There are a lot of functions in `random` that return floats. These, logically, are based on `random.random()`.
2. Older versions of Python used `random.random()` to implement `random.randrange()` and `random.randint()`. A `random.Random` subclass that doesn't provide [`getrandbits()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits), like the default implementation does, will do the same.